# how to add a preloader GIF/MP4 in HTML,CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

earlier i had used a spinner for loading my website. i want to change that into a video so i thought of editing the previous code, so what should i do to remove the spinner and add video the video in css link is https://techcraze.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/topp.mp4 please help me to place the video with help of this link
my html

```
<div class="loader_bg">
    <div class="loader" img src= "https://techcraze.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/topp.mp4"></div>
```

this is my CSS:-

```
    .load{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #000000;
    animation: AnimateBg 10s linear infinite;
    transition:  all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes animateScale{
    0%{
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    100%{
        transform: scale(0); 
    }
}

@keyframes AnimateBg{
    0%{
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.load .loader{
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.load .loader span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(calc(18deg * var(--i)));
}

.load .loader span::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ffffff ;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9B2335 ,
                0 0 20px #DFCFBE ,
                0 0 40px #55B4B0 ,
                0 0 60px #E15D44 ,
                0 0 80px #7FCDCD ,
                0 0 100px #C3447A ;
    animation: animateScale 2s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
}

.load-fin{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I think the easiest would be to convert that video into a gif and just add it with an HTML `img` tag

Comment: Use gif format and add it in a image tag ..

Comment: can you please ellaborate please!

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` Tag is only working with two (Image in Format like `.png` , `.jpg`) , (Or `.gif` file)

So if you need to add video inside your Site .. You must use `<video>` Tag like the examples below :

Video Example with Controls :

```html
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://techcraze.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/topp.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
```

Video Example without controls with autoplay feature:

```html
<video width="400" autoplay>
  <source src="https://techcraze.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/topp.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
```

Comment: so how do i add it to the preloader i totally understood your concept but how do i play it before the site loads

Comment: @sofiyansaboor55 This will be called Splash Screen .. You can google it You will find Tutorials about Splash Screen that will help you .. It will be <div> with some style to be as the whole screen  inside that <div> you will add my code above and just center it with <center> Tag .. If you need anything tell me in comments

Comment: thank you  please i have another question I have div I want to left it i have tried adding align tag but nothing works please slove my this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016930/how-to-left-align-a-frame-div-in-html